# How to convert a number of pseudorandom bits into a statistically random floating-point value between 0 and 1?

Tags: c#-4.0, floating-point, mono

I have an implementation of the xoshiro256** PRNG algorithm in an application I'm writing in C#. This works great for generating pseudorandom values between 0 and UInt64.MaxValue, but I've hit a spot where I need a pseudorandom double-precision floating-point value between 0 inclusive and 1 exclusive (so between 0 and 0.99999999...).

I know I can use BitConverter to do a "brutal conversion" from a ulong to a double, but I'm fairly certain this will give me values that are somewhere between the number of miles in a planck length and the number of cubic millimeters in the universe, and their negatives, along with the possibility of getting infinity, negative infinity, negative 0, and NaN. That's a bit ambitious (read: entirely unsuitable) for what I'm trying to do, so I'm hoping for some way of controlling the output I get so that it can be used for dealing with percent chances of things.

I don't know enough about how IEEE floating-point values work to know for sure what bits to put where in order to get the values I'm going for. I *think* (and am wrong) that I can just right-shift a ulong by 12 bits (thus turning the top 52 bits into the bottom 52 bits), add 2^52 (setting the bottom bit of the exponent to 1), and then BitConverter the resulting mess into a double. So something like this:

```
public static double DoubleFromRand(ulong rand) {
    ulong resultUL = rand >> 12;
    resultUL += ULongPow(2UL, 52UL); // adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/383596/19474638
    return BitConverter.ToDouble(BitConverter.GetBytes(resultUL), 0);
}

public static ulong ULongPow(ulong x, ulong pow) {
    ulong ret = 1UL;
    while (pow != 0UL) {
        if ((pow & 1UL) == 1UL) {
            ret *= x;
        }
        x *= x;
        pow >>= 1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If this worked, I would expect that passing UInt64.MaxValue to this would give me some value very close to 1 but not quite there. What I actually get from the above algorithm is some really weird small value.

Any clue what to do here? Using C# 4.0 on Mono 6.8.0.105, on Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit, on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. Note that I am not interested in using "real" .NET.

(Related: [How to convert a uint64_t to a double/float between 0 and 1 with maximum accuracy (C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901022/how-to-convert-a-uint64-t-to-a-double-float-between-0-and-1-with-maximum-accurac) This doesn't answer my question as it converts a ulong to a double with mathematical operations, which I believe doesn't guarantee the statistical randomness of the result.

Also answers relating on how to use the built-in random features of C# are not helpful as I want to use my own implementation of a PRNG. I also am not helped by answers about how to generate random 64-bit floats. I want, very specifically, to take some quantity of randomly generated bits and force-convert them into a float that will land between 0 and 1. The question is about how to do the conversion, not the generation of random things.)

Comment: Try `double DoubleFromRand(ulong rand) { return (double)(rand >> 12)/(1ul << 52); }`.

Comment: Do not try to fabricate the representation of a `double`. Simply get 52 random bits as a binary numeral, convert them to a `double` (as a plain integer-to-`double` conversion), and multiply by 2^−52 to scale to [0, 1). That is what chux code above does, and it is fine for most applications.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Actually, you can get **53** bits, due to IEEE 754's hidden bit trick giving you an extra bit of precision.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Hmm, it appears that my code and chux code are doing the same thing, but chux code is obviously more portable. That might work then.

Comment: @dan04: Yes, 53.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach to converts "bits into a statistically random floating-point value between 0 and 1?" begins with converting such bits into a value between [1.0 ... 2.0) and then subtracting 1.0.

Floating point numbers are distributed *linearly* between successive *powers-of-2*.

With common `double` [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), there are 2<sup>52</sup> values between most powers of 2.  So take the 64-bits of random data and reduce to 52 and form a random number [1.0... 2.0) (OP's code does this with various bit manipulations), then subtract 1.0.

This is OP's self-answer [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75990335/2410359).

When done well, it provides a fast approach, yet has additional portability issues over the following.

---

Another approach is to use 52 of the 64 supplied random bits and form a value [0...2<sup>52</sup>-1] and divide by 2<sup>52</sup>.  The shift, conversion from `ulong` to `double` and division are all expected to be *exact* and not dependent on rounding mode.  Thus we prevent statistical biases from creeping in, yet only form 2<sup>52</sup> different values.

```
// Something like
double DoubleFromRand(ulong rand) { 
  return (double)(rand >> 12)/(1ul << 52);
}
```

---

We can even use 1 bit more [@dan04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75989802/how-to-convert-a-number-of-pseudorandom-bits-into-a-statistically-random-floatin/75991248?noredirect=1#comment134026553_75989802)
 and still have  "shift, conversion from `ulong` to `double` and division are all expected to be *exact* and not dependent on rounding mode". Using more than 53 bits loses this property.

```
double DoubleFromRand53(ulong rand) {
  return (double)(rand >> 11)/(1ul << 53);
}
```

---

Another approach, not shown, would use 64 of the 64 bits and form a value [0...2<sup>64</sup>-1] and divide by 2<sup>64</sup>.  This unfortunately incurs rounding in the integer to conversion and more rounding in the division imparting an undesirable bias and range (1.0 may get returned), yet does provide closer to 2<sup>64</sup> different values.

Comment: As dan04 noted, we can use 53 bits. There are 2^52 representable numbers in [½, 1), and we can use 2^52 numbers with the same spacing in [0, ½), making 2^53 for [0, 1).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, I recall that now too.  Answer amended.

Comment: I benchmarked my original solution versus this solution, and discovered that the solution in this answer is multiple times faster than my BitConverter gymnastics. So it's a full-on win in every way - it's portable, safe, and fast.

Answer (score 0):

(Edit: As pointed out in the comments in my question, this isn't a great way of doing things, but for in the event someone has a good reason to do this sort of thing, I'll leave this here. Also, this is multiple *times* slower than the solution by chux, so use theirs unless you have a really good reason not to.)

I think I figured it out after some experimentation.

The exponent field uses a value of 1023 to represent 0 - larger values are positive, smaller ones are negative. So a value of 1023 in the exponent allows the rest of the significand field to be interpreted "as-is", i.e. - everything after the decimal point in the number.

Doing this makes `UInt64.MaxValue` map to ~1.999, which is *almost* 2 (and it will print as 2 if you use `Console.WriteLine()` on it without setting the number of digits to display). `UInt64.MaxValue / 2` maps to 1.5, `UInt64.MaxValue / 4` maps to 1.25.

Which is great except for the fact that there's an extra 1.0 on all of these values. Thankfully it looks like I can get rid of that by simply subtracting 1.0 from the final result. This appears to be working at first glance (`UInt64.MaxValue / 4` now maps to 0.25). I'm not sure if this will cause errors with smaller values, but hopefully it won't.

The final I-think-it's-working code is:

```
public static double DoubleFromRand(ulong rand) {
    ulong resultUL = rand >> 12;
    resultUL += ((ulong)1023 << 52);
    return BitConverter.ToDouble(BitConverter.GetBytes(resultUL), 0) - 1.0;
}
```

Note that this mess is probably not portable across all processors - according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (where I got all my info about IEEE754 floating-point math), some CPUs do really weird things with endianness when working with floating-point numbers, so depending on your CPU, this may give you seriously scrambled results. But so far, on my particular 64-bit ARM CPU, this seems to work.