# Converting u64 to f64 between 0..1

Tags: rust, random, floating-point, simd

I need a very fast pseudorandom number generator for a project I've been working on. So far, I've implemented the xorshift algorithm and can generate pseudorandom u64s. However, I need to convert these u64s to a floating point value in the range between 0 and 1.

I've been primarily using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75989802/how-to-convert-a-number-of-pseudorandom-bits-into-a-statistically-random-floatin) and [this](https://blog.bithole.dev/blogposts/random-float/) as reference.

For some reason I can't get anywhere close to the behavior I want; this is confusing to me as I've used the exact same method as found [here](https://github.com/rust-random/rand/blob/master/src/distributions/float.rs). Despite me seeing no difference in the implementations, I get different results.

```rust
    let seeds: [u64; 64] = core::array::from_fn(|i| i as u64);

    let bitshift12 = u64x64::splat(12);
    let bitshift25 = u64x64::splat(25);
    let bitshift27 = u64x64::splat(27);
    
    let bitshift52 = u64x64::splat(52);
    
    let mut random_states = Simd::from(seeds);
    
    random_states ^= random_states >> bitshift12;
    random_states ^= random_states << bitshift25;
    random_states ^= random_states >> bitshift27;
    
    random_states = random_states | ((u64x64::splat(1023) + u64x64::splat(0)) << bitshift52);
    
    let mut generated = Simd::<f64, 64>::from_bits(random_states);
    
    println!("{:?}", generated);
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 1.0000000074505808, 1.0000000149011616, 1.0000000223517425, 1.0000000298023235, 1.0000000372529039, ...]
```

Obviously I didn't do something properly as the last few decimals are "random" as needed. Why can't I properly shift these up?

If anyone point out my error(s) it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing `from_bits`?  The values you are generating look nothing like floating point numbers.  If your range is 64 bits, then just divide the integers by 2^63.

Comment: @Tim Roberts That was my first intuition and attempt. It pretty much only gives me numbers in the 10^-12 range. I suppose I can then multiply by a constant to get it in the range I want, but all these operations are too expensive. I used `from_bits` as I tried to take the implementation from an existing crate; that is what they used.

Comment: @PeterCordes You're absolutely correct. I just quickly tested with a larger set of "real" seeds by punching in some large u64s. I get pretty much the behavior I want.

Comment: @PeterCordes The idea about randomizing just the mantissa is actually pretty good; I like that a lot.

Comment: @PeterCordes Can you elaborate on why using SIMD vectors here would be inefficient? For my application I would need to generate anywhere from 10s to 1000s of "random" numbers (always powers of 2) at once. I figured breaking it into SIMD vectors would be more efficient. Also yeah, sorry about the 0. I had that there because I was experimenting with adding different exponent values; I forgot to remove it before posting.

Comment: Looking now at the other Q&As you linked, it's exactly what Chux's answer on [How to convert a number of pseudorandom bits into a statistically random floating-point value between 0 and 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75989802) suggested was the standard technique, of forming a `[1.0, 2.0)` value and subtracting 1.0.  I'm not sure why they say there might be portability problems, though; that subtraction should be exact.  Maybe they mean to C# implementations that don't use IEEE FP? Or from doing the bit-stuffing?

Comment: x86 doesn't have packed-SIMD u64 to f64 conversion until AVX-512 for chux's suggested method, although it can be emulated fairly cheaply.  [How to efficiently perform double/int64 conversions with SSE/AVX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41144668)

Comment: @PeterCordes It is very interesting that AVX does not have specific instructions for converting integers to double precision. I won't pretend I know much about any of this; I assumed that since Rust provided me with all the same operations on 64 lane SIMD, the instructions existed. Also I apologize I didn't mean to ignore that portion of your comment --truth is I don't really understand it! I am not really that knowledgeable about very low-level stuff, especially anything with assembly.

Comment: SSE/AVX does have `i32` to/from `f64` in hardware, but not `i64`, `u64`, or even `u32`.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtdq2pd is the instruction for it.  C intrinsic `_mm256_cvtepi32_pd`.  (And yeah, I figured there was a good chance you just didn't understand that comment, sorry for being snarky about it.  I did try to start with something comprehensible like `random_states >> 12` that I'd hope would compile because.  If it doesn't and you have to splat a vector of counts, then I guess the API is designed around compilers optimizing away the vector constants.)

Comment: Yeah, I do need to do a shift using a vector of counts; that wasn't just poor design on my end --there is no other way. Rust SIMD vectors only implement shifts with other SIMD vectors of compatible type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That sequence looks like what you'd get from stuffing small integers into the mantissas of `f64` bit-patterns with the exponent from 1.0, so you get 1.0 plus tiny amounts. Not as small as `0, 1, 2, 3, ...`; https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=049046048048048048048048048048055052053048053056048056 shows that number is represented by the `f64` bit-pattern `0x3FF0000002000001` which just has 2 bits set in the mantissa.

That looks like the bit-pattern you'd get after iteration of xoshiro starting with seed = 1, though. Note the first shift is to the right, shifting out the only bit leaving 0.  The next step is left, leading to two set bits.  Then the final right-shift by 27 shifts them both out, again xoring with 0 leaving them unmodified.

**So your extremely non-random seed of `seeds[i] = i` after just one step of xoshiro leads to these non-random mantissas.** (And `seeds[0]` will never become non-zero; xoshiro needs non-zero seeds because shift and xor can never create a non-zero bit from zero.)

If you did have uniform random `u64` values (e.g. from using a real seed, or letting the generator run many iterations for the non-zero seeds), ORing them with the exponent from `1.0` would randomize the exponent as well, leading to huge values. But always larger in magnitude than 1.0, except for NaN with all-ones exponent (or infinity if the mantissa was zero).  Also a random sign.  OR can't clear bits, and IEEE float magnitude increases monotonically with increasing integer bit-pattern, thanks to the exponent bias.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

If you mask the random `u64` to keep only the low 52 bits so you're just randomizing the mantissa, you can easily get uniform random numbers in `[1.0, 2.0)`.  As Chux says, in the Q&A you linked (*[How to convert a number of pseudorandom bits into a statistically random floating-point value between 0 and 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75989802/how-to-convert-a-number-of-pseudorandom-bits-into-a-statistically-random-floatin)*), subtracting `1.0` from that is a standard way to get a `[0.0, 1.0)` number.

The closer to 0.0 (the smaller the exponent), the more trailing zeros the mantissa will have after cancellation from subtracting two nearby numbers: the smaller the exponent, the closer together the representable values are, but we want a uniform distribution.  There are only 52 bits of entropy from this method.  This is probably fine, but in theory you could check the exponent field and use a variable-count shift + OR to randomize the low mantissa bits.

Chux's other method (of value-preserving conversion, like a C cast) and then division (actually multiplication by an inverse) can't be done as efficiently on x86 without AVX-512 for packed conversion from `u64` to `f64`.  *[How to efficiently perform double/int64 conversions with SSE/AVX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144668/how-to-efficiently-perform-double-int64-conversions-with-sse-avx)* - it takes multiple instructions, more than for replacing the exponent and subtracting.  (And with AVX-512, replacing the exponent field also becomes more efficient, just a single `vpternlogd` with a bitmask covering the exponent+sign field.)

---

BTW, this using SIMD vectors of shift counts doesn't look efficient unless the compiler optimizes `u64x64 bitshift12` back to a scalar immediate.  On x86 and AArch64 at least, vector shifts can use a scalar count, so I'd hope that `random_states >> 12` would compile to `vpsrlq ymm, ymm, 12` (with AVX2), not needing AVX2 variable-count shifts with vector constants for the counts like `vpsrlvq ymm, ymm, ymm`.  (One per 2 cycle throughput on Zen 2 vs. one per cycle for immediate-count shifts: https://uops.info/.  But on Zen 3 and later, and Intel Skylake and later, throughputs are the same.  But if the compiler is actually having to load vectors of counts from an array of 64x `u64`, that sucks).

I assume `u64x64::splat(1023) + u64x64::splat(0)` was there to play with different exponent fields, but why vector add?  Just `u64x64::splat((1023 + offset) << 52)` will give you the exponent field from 1.0, doing all math with scalar constants that won't even tempt the compiler into doing it at run-time.

Comment: Since I don't have more than 15 reputation I (unfortunately) can't upvote this answer. However, do know that this has been incredibly helpful in fixing my problem and providing a deeper understanding.

Comment: Just to add link to the answer https://www.corsix.org/content/higher-quality-random-floats